# Can we prevent clickjacking from Client Side rendered React JS Application?

Tags: reactjs, client-side, content-security-policy, x-frame-options, clickjacking

I have a client-side react application. I want to prevent my website to be opened by any other website in its iframe.
I see using the X-Frame-Options set in the header is an option. But can that be done from the client application? Or it needs to be done from the server-side only?
Any best methods to apply clickjacking to the client-side react application will be helpful for my application.

Comment: Yes, `X-Frame-Optios` and `Content Security-Policy` HTTP response headers can pe published an server-side only. Note that `frame-ancestors` directive is not supported in the `Content Security-Policy` meta tag.

Comment: Could you figure it out? I landed here while trying to find answer of the same question

Comment: @HimaChhag same! Did you figure it out? haha

Comment: Yep, I did figure it out. I will post my solution @user15575918

Answer (score 3):

```
const UnsecuredPageWarning = styled.h1`
      color: red;
    `;
 
const Link = styled.a`
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
`;

const UnsecuredPage: FunctionComponent = (): ReactElement => (
  <div>
    <UnsecuredPageWarning>If you see this page, Webb App link you have clicked on is under Clickjacking security attack.</UnsecuredPageWarning>
    <h2>Please inform team with the reference of the application from where you clicked this link.</h2>
    <h2>Click <Link href={window.self.location.href} title='Web Application' target='blank'>here</Link> to access WebApp safely.</h2>
  </div>
);
 
// Won't render the application if WebApp is under Clickjacking attack
if(window.self === window.top) {
  ReactDOM.render(<WrappedApp />, document.getElementsByClassName('app')[0]);
} else{
  ReactDOM.render(<UnsecuredPage />, document.getElementsByClassName('app')[0]);
}
```

Also tested the above code with the below html in WebPage

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Clickjack test page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="http://localhost:3000/login" width="900" height="300"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```